# Vbs CopyFile not working properly

Tags: vbscript, file-copying

I have a script that just stopped working a few days ago, when it had been working for the past three months. The script runs from a user's local drive, and only fails for a few users. Both popups are displayed, so I know both source and destination exist. The strange thing is, I added the last if statement when trying to figure out this issue, and that copy works. Has anyone ever seen this happen? What am I missing here?

```
set ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strLocalFolder = "C:\USERS\MyLocalFolder\" 

strRemoteFile = "\\ServerName\RemoteFolder\test.dat"

If (objFSO.FileExists (strRemoteFile )) Then 
    ws.Popup "Found file " & strRemoteFile 
End If

If (objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalFolder )) Then 
    ws.Popup "Found folder " & strLocalFolder 
End If

objFSO.CopyFile strRemoteFile, strLocalFolder, True

If (objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalFolder )) Then   
    objFSO.CopyFile  strRemoteFile, strLocalFolder, True
End If
```

Comment: The error I am receiving is "File not found"

Comment: Therefore it doesn't work?

Comment: Correct. The first copy does not work but the second one does. I'm trying to find the root cause of the error.

Comment: No user as permissions to create a folder or file in Users. Also help says *Note that CopyFile will fail if destination has the read-only attribute set, regardless of the value of overwrite.*

Comment: If that is the case, why is the second copy (second to last line) successful?

Comment: There are identical, however that is a poor programming pattern. Never test then do, always do then catch any errors. You force two disk accesses which chews battery power.